# Cocoapods containing/accessing own Core Data Model

Tags: ios, core-data, cocoapods

Is it possible in the current release of **Cocoapods** for a pod to define and access a Core Data **xcdatamodeld**?

Current forum post range from workarounds to currently implemented and local attempts have resulted in generated models being renamed to **model.mmod**

Comment: Perhaps you can rephrase your question. Cocoapods itself does not "access" anything. It simply downloads your dependencies from the internet/custom sources and builds your workspace project. Are you trying to use a particular Pod?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As cocoapods can basically provide any kind of file, it can also provide a `xcdatamodeld`.

Comment: @Mundi Will you please elaborate more on that I mean how to do that

Comment: Put the `xcdatamoeld` into the pods repo. :).